# Using pywinauto to click dialog box Cancel button

Tags: python, windows, pywinauto

I have a situation where an automation process for PowerPoint gets hung up if a password protected .ppt file is passed into it. I've worked out a script to detect when this happens using `pywinauto` and hook up to the Password dialog but I can't seem to get it to click the Cancel button.

Here's the control identifiers I see for the Enter Password dialog:

```
NUIDialog - 'Password'    (L649, T422, R999, B553)
['NUIDialog', 'Password', 'PasswordNUIDialog']
child_window(title="Password", class_name="NUIDialog")
   |
   | NetUIHWND - ''    (L657, T453, R991, B545)
   | ['NetUIHWND', 'PasswordNetUIHWND']
   | child_window(class_name="NetUIHWND")
   |    |
   |    | NetUICtrlNotifySink - ''    (L728, T495, R983, B510)
   |    | ['PasswordNetUICtrlNotifySink', 'NetUICtrlNotifySink']
   |    | child_window(class_name="NetUICtrlNotifySink")
   |    |    |
   |    |    | RICHEDIT60W - ''    (L728, T495, R983, B510)
   |    |    | ['PasswordRICHEDIT60W', 'RICHEDIT60W']
   |    |    | child_window(class_name="RICHEDIT60W")
   |    |
   |    | RICHEDIT60W - ''    (L728, T495, R983, B510)
   |    | ['PasswordRICHEDIT60W', 'RICHEDIT60W']
   |    | child_window(class_name="RICHEDIT60W")
   |
   | NetUICtrlNotifySink - ''    (L728, T495, R983, B510)
   | ['PasswordNetUICtrlNotifySink', 'NetUICtrlNotifySink']
   | child_window(class_name="NetUICtrlNotifySink")
   |    |
   |    | RICHEDIT60W - ''    (L728, T495, R983, B510)
   |    | ['PasswordRICHEDIT60W', 'RICHEDIT60W']
   |    | child_window(class_name="RICHEDIT60W")
   |
   | RICHEDIT60W - ''    (L728, T495, R983, B510)
   | ['PasswordRICHEDIT60W', 'RICHEDIT60W']
   | child_window(class_name="RICHEDIT60W")
```

I tried doing a `password_dialog.NetUICtrlNotifySink.Click()` but nothing happens. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using default `Application(backend="win32")`?

Comment: @VasilyRyabov I wasn't so I tried it but it produces the same control identifiers list.

Comment: Yes, because it's default backend. But there is one more `backend="uia"` which should produce another identifiers list probably. Did you try it?

Comment: I would recommend using `backend="uia"` for all MS Office products. It should see much more controls.

Comment: That did it. I switched and was able to find the Cancel button and click it. Thank you!

Comment: Cool! Posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using `Application(backend="uia")` for all MS Office products. It should see much more controls.